# OData 8 - Custom routing with named parameters that do not care about order

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api, odata, .net-6.0, asp.net-routing

In the **.NET Framework 4.8** version of the API I'm working on, I could specify the routing to an endpoint as so:
`[ODataRoute("/myEndpoint(FirstName={firstName},LastName={lastName})/Data")]`

This would accept queries regardless of their **named** parameter order, so both:
`"~odata/myEndpoint(FirstName=John,LastName=Doe)/Data"` Success ✔️
`"~odata/myEndpoint(LastName=Doe,FirstName=John)/Data"` Success ✔️
would produce results.

However, now in the **.NET 6** version (and oData 8 upgrade), that seems no longer to be the case. So from a route specified by (based on the [docs](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/odata/attribute-routing-in-asp-net-core-odata-8-0-rc/#attribute-routing-using-http-verb-attributes) and using the ASP.NET routing parameters):
`[HttpGet("/myEndpoint(FirstName={firstName},LastName={lastName})/Data")]`

The results would be :
`"~odata/myEndpoint(FirstName=John,LastName=Doe)/Data"` - Success ✔️
`"~odata/myEndpoint(LastName=Doe,FirstName=John)/Data"` - 404 ❌

Is there a way to configure the oData 8 to be able to map a query to an ednpoint, regardless of the order of its named parameters passed in the URL? Or is it up to me to implement it as a middleware somehow? Would there be anything within the package that could assist me in the process?